# Confusion in setting up mcrypt php extension on Yosemite

Tags: php, osx-yosemite, mcrypt

I am following this tutorial http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-development-server/ but I have some confusion:

Firstly, regarding "change directory (cd) to the home account and make a directory that you will work in, call it mcrypt". Which one is the home account: Is it the one that I am in when I first run the terminal?

Secondly, I have a PHP of version 5.5.20 and when I run phpinfo(), the extension_dir is shown at `/usr/lib/php/extensions`. When I run this command `cd usr/lib/php/extensions/mcrypt/` (to compile mycypt PHP extension), there is no such directory (mcrypt folder is not there).

Comment: Your home dir is `~` (which is equal to `/Users/yourName`). `cd ~ ; mkdir mcrypt` chdirs to your home and makes a dir `mcrypt` in there.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the first one right. But do you know if I am doing the right thing here: for this suggested command: **cd ../php-5.5.9/ext/mcrypt/** , I substituted **cd usr/lib/php/extensions/mcrypt/**. Is that right???

Comment: No. This path refers to the php source code folder which has been downloaded on step 2 and should be in your home.

Comment: Thanks a lot georg, all is now working fine. Earlier alone I had neglected installing the php code.